# python - Overloading operators on the fly

Tags: python, operator-overloading, overriding, overloading

I would like to know, if there is a way to overload operators in Python in runtime. For instance:

```
class A:
   pass
a = A()
a.__str__ = lambda self: "noice"
print(str(a))
```

The desired output is `"noice"`, but the given code uses `object`'s implementation of the `str` function instead, yielding something along the lines: `<__main__.A object at 0x000001CAB2051490>`.

Why doesn't the code use my overriden implementation of the function overload?

Python version used is `3.9.2`.

Comment: you can only overload the class methods at runtime but not the methods of the instances of that class

Comment: Do you actually want `a` to have a `__str__` that works differently from other instances of the `A` class? If so, why? Or do you only want to change the class' `__str__` after the fact?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972/adding-a-method-to-an-existing-object-instance answer your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `str(a)`, it resolves to the equivalent of `a.__class__.__str__(a)`, not `a.__str__()`.

```
>>> A.__str__ = lambda self: "noice"
>>> str(a)
'noice'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to assign that function to the class, not an instance of the class.

```
>>> class A:
...     pass
...
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__str__ = lambda x: 'hi'
>>> print(a)
<__main__.A object at 0x000000A4D16C1D30>
>>> A.__str__ = lambda x: 'hi'
>>> print(a)
hi
```